# What are some real world examples of screened subnet firewall architecture?

Tags: firewalls

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Public DMZ network architecture](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/13556/public-dmz-network-architecture)

screened subnet firewall architecture has a DMZ
the outisde world doesnt know about the inside network beyond DMZ
and inside doesnt know about internet

then what are the real world use cases ?

Comment: Duplicate of both http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/13556/public-dmz-network-architecture and http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/4968/what-is-best-practice-for-separation-of-trusted-zones-from-a-dmz-with-a-single-f

Comment: You could also read this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DMZ_%28computing%29